# Does $m*n \iff (m, n)=n$ define a partial order / an equivalence relation on $\{1,\ldots, 9\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

$Note: (m, n) = n$ means that the greatest common divisor between $m$ and $n$ is $n$.

The relation $*$ is reflexive because, being $x$ any element of $A$,

$x * x$ since $(x, x) = x$

The $*$ relation isn't symmetric, for example,

$2*1$  but  $1\require{cancel} \cancel{*}2$

*Is it correct and is it well demonstrated what I did? Also, I can not see if the relation is transitive and / or antisymmetric.*

Comment: It probably helps to realize that $\gcd(m,n)=n$ is the same as  $n\mid m$.

Comment: What you have done is correct.  What is giving you difficulty on the others?  Do you know the definitions of antisymmetry and transitivity?  Can you write down what it means for * to be antisymmetric?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I know the definitions. I think it's transitivity but it's hard for me to prove it, I just think of writing all the elements that belong to the relation and listing those that are transitive but I do not think it's a very clean way to demonstrate the transitvity

Comment: @Joffan's comment helps a lot at proving transitivity.

Comment: If you look at Joffan's comment, I think you will be able to prove transitivity very quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to start working with what Joffan said.

Comment: Would the demonstration of transitivity be like that ?:
$*$ is transitive since given three elements of $A x*y$ and $y*c$ then $x*c$ and this is verified since if $a|b$ and $b|c$ then $a|c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  $$(m, n) = n \iff n|m$$

Thus the relation  on $A$ is reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric and of course not symmetric.

The antisymmetric part is because all elements of A are positive so if $ n|m $ and $ m|n$, then $m=n$.